# test app on iphone certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, key

yesterday  I have bought the developer account for to test my app on iPhone.I read a lot of tutorials,both here that other places, but i have problems about the authorization certificate and xcode gives me a this error:
"The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains".

Can you help me for please, yesterday i have spent 99$ and I still have not done anything.

I thank you for your attention and availability

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you are following steps listed at :- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-install-apps-on-iphone-devices-for-development/